# Genetic learn fuzzy systems

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, fuzzy

I need to create genetic algorithm to learn fuzzy systems. I know how work each of them. But my problem is how to do learn fuzzy systems by GA.

I want to implement this algorithm in Michigan type. It means one rule in one chromosome. And now i have algrithm with chromosoms e.g [1 2 2] means IF x1 is small and x2 is medium then y1 is medium. What to do next? I need to implement this for sets PID regulator parameters. I need to create some rule base. But for what? And how to check which one of chromosome is better? My adaptation function is setting time and rise time from last generetion.

Comment: Basically you are describing the general methodology. Have you tried something by now? You could try the Genetic Algorithm matlab function, and share us the results you are getting. And read some other matlab codes and examples available on internet.

Comment: i have already AG with simple crossing and mutations methods. My only problem is with adaptation function. I know is wrong. Now i choose better population by first two parameters.

[1 2 1 2 3]

if setTime is small and riseTime is medium then Kp change -1 and Ki not change and Kd change +2;

if first two paramers is correct then is more adaptated.

Comment: Could you elaborate in the question?

Comment: main question is: How should look like adaptation function to my app?

Comment: Nobody in here will clone your ideas or methods :). So again, elaborate your question, paste all your information, methods, papers writings and data, and then the problem and solution will be clear. You are asking "solve my problem now" without investing in explaining deeply.

Comment: Also try to learn from existing code on google, and ask when you have a clear precise question, not a general doubt on how to understand the method.